# Sphinx don't match correct symbols

Tags: php, mysql, search, full-text-search, sphinx

I have a problem with sphinx search 
For example the query is 'C++'

For this query I get results that match 'C' but I need sphinx to search exact 'C++' not 'C'

Comment: I'm not sure about sphinx but this could be an encoding problem.  For example `+` in a URL is used to represent a space character, so you'd better make sure they are encoded/decoded correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Check your `charset_table`, 
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-charset-table

Suspect you dont have + in your `charset_table`, so it isnt been indexed.

Or if you just want to deal with specific cases (like `c++`) and not all cases of that char (like `1+2`), then look at adding an exception for `c++`
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-exceptions
(its even in the example!)

Answer (score 0):

- is an arithmetic character and will not be matched

You should look at exceptions to around this issue:

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/1.10/conf-exceptions.html

```
C++ => cplusplus
c++ => cplusplus
```